# Visualizing lat/lon pairs on a map, locally

Tags: google-maps, coordinates, google-maps-api, maps, privacy

I have a sensitive list of coordinates that I've already managed to geocode locally and now need to visualize on an interactive map. They're all contained within a particular neighborhood of the same city, so I'm hoping there's a way to display these on a map as pins, like one would do with the Google Maps API, but by downloading the map of the area and then adding the pins rather than sending the list of the pins and their data over the Internet. How might I get these points visualized on a map in a way that preserves the privacy of the coordinates?

Answer (score 1):

[Leaflet](http://leafletjs.com/examples.html) will render your map markers locally.